# python condition make wrong result

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new in python and I have a question about while loops.

Can someone explain me what exactly happens with my code and why it gives me an incorrect result.

This is my code:

```
age=20

while age >= 10:
    age=int(input("what is your age?")) 
    print("your age is >= 10")
```

and response is this:

```
  what is your age? 9
  "your age is >= 10"
```

I am not understanding this. I am using windows7 & python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are printing "your age is >= 10" after asking the age, but not actually checking what age they entered first. You should use a conditional statement around the print to prevent it from printing if the age isn't >= 10.

```
age=20

while age >= 10:
    age=int(input("what is your age?"))
    if age >= 10: 
        print("your age is >= 10")
```

Comment: I would suggest changing `while age >= 10:` into `while True` and add an `else: break` branch to the `if`, so that the condition is not checked twice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this code? It would help clarifying.

Input is a function that takes the string `"what is your age?"`, prompts the user, and returns the answer the user inputs in the command line. The function `int()` then casts the user answer from string into an integer. After, this integer is assigned to the variable age `age=`, and then prints a message saying `"your age is >= 10"`

What happens is every time the loop runs, the program asks the user for his age, and assign it to the variable age. Then the `while` loop checks for the condition: is age equal or larger than 10? `age >= 10`. If it is not, it keeps looping. It will only exit the loop if the user inputs an age that is smaller than 10.

Hope it helps.